# Developing on android-based device via wireless

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

One known way to develop your android application directly onto the device is using the usb connector and install the driver using eclipse. As such, is there a known way to do this wireless?

EDIT:
Ideally this shouldn't require rooted device.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UPDATE: This is now natively supported with recent SDKs. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) under "Wireless Usage".

In short:

- Connect to your device via USB
- Enter "adb tcpip 5555"
- Unplug your device
- Look up your device's IP in the system settings
- Enter "adb connect [ip address]:5555"
- That's it!

---

For the record, here is the old version of the answer:

Install the wireless ADB app. Details here: http://www.androidcentral.com/android-quick-app-adb-wireless

EDIT: Okay, that one requires root. If you don't have root, it's going to be a bit more cumbersome. Off the top of my head, here's what you can do:

- Use any means of wireless transfer (Bluetooth or FTP, there are lots of apps for either on the market) to transfer the APK file from your computer to the phone.
- Use a file manager (OI File Manager, for example) to navigate to the file and open it.

Step 1 can be automated through the command line if you're using FTP (and, at least on Unix-based systems, most likely via Bluetooth as well).

Step 2, well, cannot be simplified THAT easily. But you could write an installer app that simply does an ACTION_VIEW on the APK file on your phone.

Obviously, this will go through the package installer, so you'll have to confirm the installation process and everything. But hey, it's wireless :)

(Side note: There are several telnetd and sshd solutions on Android, but none that I could find are for non-rooted phones. If you can get a telnet/ssh connection going, you may be able to make this process more comfortable.)

Comment: Oh this looks useful, but I forgot to mention since I borrow the device from my friend, I need one that doesn't require root. Upvoted anyhow :)

Comment: My bad! I'm so used to rooting that I don't even realize if something is root-only! Anyway, I'll edit the answer for more info.

Comment: If you are willing to put it on a non-standard higher (unprivileged) port number, it should be entirely possible to do a telnetd or sshd that runs as an unprivileged user - but it would only be able to do the things an ordinary application user could.

Comment: @EboMike: I setup everything and is working fine. However, I wonder how secure this really is. Anyone inside your network can install and run ANY app when you press that green button!? All he needs to know is your IP...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there isn't some form of adb already running?  Look in settings for anything about enabling debugging.  Get a terminal emulator app such as connectbot, start it up and do 'ps' to see what is running.

If you post the name of the tablet (and google it!) there might be some known solutions already

Comment: Yeah I can get it to debug but via USB, what I wanted to know is whether there's a way to do that without having to use USB (i.e. wireless). Thank's anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

For those who have a rooted phone can use an app from Google Play which simplifies very much making a wireless connection. Try this one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en. It worked for me.