# Android Studio Adb not working while tethering

Tags: android, android-studio

My laptop WiFi adapter is not working, so basically I'm using internet through phone tethering.

Apparently this make ADB not working. This is the error I got:

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:93: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
```

If i try to kill the Adb, by running `adb kill-server`, I'll got:

```
Cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

If I stop phone tethering, ADB will run just fine and I can start the emulator. Is there a way to run ADB while at the same time use internet through phone tethering?

Comment: There is a discussion of a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831807/usb-tether-and-debug-at-the-same-time), maybe you will find something helpful among the answers.